# Jenkins-Unable to copy binaries to a shared remote folder(Windows)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am building  a Jenkins pipeline for the ASP Dotnet project with basic three steps:1. GitCode download2. Build the code and 3. Deploy the Binary to the remote machine(By copying binaried to a shared folder)
I have  Jenkins installed on Windows OS on the host and remote server as well Both machines can ping each other.

I am facing a problem in step # 3 to copy Binary files from the Jenkins server(windows) to another Window server(deployment server).  For that, I am using the command line to copy the file to the desired share folder. 
When I copy files using the command-line interface,  it is happening without any error, but when I run through Jenkins it is giving me an error:

[compile] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\jenkins8062217538120121374.batC:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\MES\compile>xcopy /h /i /c /k /e /r /y D:\www\workspace \192.16.8.15\public\shared\aspweb\ Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\MES\compile>exit 4 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failureArchiving artifacts

However the command "xcopy /h /i /c /k /e /r /y D:\www\workspace \192.16.8.15\public\shared\aspweb" is aboutltely working fine in Window's commnad line.Please help me.

Apart from the above, Could you please help me to know:

1. What is the best approach for the deployment
2. Is following master/slave approach a good idea ( In this approach the drawback is, for multiple node the entire code get downloaded on slave and build it, so didn't prefer this approach)
3. Any other good approach

Comment: I got the solution doing it by Master-agent way. Build job of the code received from Git is done by the master and the rest of the job is asked to done by the agent.

Comment: you can try robocopy, which has nice feature. i think the destiation networkfolder should start with \\